# не работает директива nopreempt в keeapalived

Tags: centos

У меня проблема в том что отказывается работать директива nopreempt в keeapalived, настраивал на centos/7 как из репозитория так и последний скомпилированный из исходников.
Собственно вопрос не сложный, работает ли эта штука, и что нужно сделать еще дополнительно.

конфиг такой:

---

для master

```
! Configuration File for keepalived

global_defs {
   notification_email {
   }
   vrrp_skip_check_adv_addr
   vrrp_strict
   vrrp_garp_interval 0
   vrrp_gna_interval 0
}


vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    strict_mode off
    state MASTER
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 100
    advert_int 1
    unicast_src_ip 192.168.199.171
    unicast_peer {
        192.168.199.172
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.199.20
    }
}
```

---

для backup

```
! Configuration File for keepalived

global_defs {
   notification_email {
   }
   vrrp_skip_check_adv_addr
   vrrp_strict
   vrrp_garp_interval 0
   vrrp_gna_interval 0
}

vrrp_instance VI_1 {
    strict_mode off
    state BACKUP
    interface eth0
    virtual_router_id 51
    priority 90
    advert_int 1
    nopreempt
    unicast_src_ip 192.168.199.172
    unicast_peer {
        192.168.199.171
    }
    virtual_ipaddress {
        192.168.199.20
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

В выводе интерфейса eth0 с помощью команды **ip a** или **ifconfig** должна появиться дополнительная  строка inet с твоим виртуальным ip-адресом. Либо если ты в блоке virtual_ipaddress к виртуальному ip-адресу допишешь label, то в выводе **ip a** или **ifconfig** будет показываться как отдельный интрефейс. Укажи, кстати, нужный интрефейс, через который будет "ходить" виртуальный ip в этом же блоке.